# go get golang package and run a script automatically

Tags: go

when we publish python package, we use pip, which will trigger setup.py to build some necessary packages.

I'm publishing a golang package, I wish when my user gets my package, it will auto trigger a makefile (some scripts to prepare environment) before installation. Is it possible?

Comment: If you need some things to happen before building, use `go generate`. Otherwise, adhere to separation of concerns and make a separate project with the capability of setting the former one up. Auto-running code on build/get is a security concern; it isn't possible.

Comment: Note that go generate does not run automatically. It still has to be triggered manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish when my user get my package, it will auto trigger an makefile (some scirpts) before installation.

That would allow *you* to execute arbitrary commands on *my* machine while I do some innocent looking `go get github.com/yiw/totallyharmless` because I want to use that package.

> Is it possible?

I hope not. This happened in the past (through clever cgo stuff) and was fixed as this is a major security issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have noted this security issue from your reply. Thanks~!